# Trying to retreive int type from function and compare it with $_Get value (mysql PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I trying to  retreive int type from database and compare it with $_Get value

Here is the code for when the user click on the button

```
if(isset($_GET['btn_placeorder']))
{


$Quantity_Ordered=(int)$_GET['Quantity_Ordered'];


**# retreivng another value from function to compare it as integer**
$number= (int)$auth_user->Blood_Bankavaliable        ($Blood_BankID,$Type_Ordered);

  try
   {

     if ($Type_Ordered=="" || $Quantity_Ordered=="")
    {
    $error[] = "Valid data is required!";   
}

else if($Quantity_Ordered >$number) {
    $error[] = "This Number is not avaliable in our Stock !";
}
```

**Here is the code for the function**

```
function  Blood_Bankavaliable($blood_bankID,$Type_Ordered) {
      global $conn;
# query for getting the value from the database
    $query = "select sum(Blood_quantity) as d from Donor_Blood_Bank   where     Blood_Type=$Type_Ordered and blood_bankID= $blood_bankID";
  try {

    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
   $result = $statement->fetchall;

   return $result;
} catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

}

I don't know what is the problem with my code  any help?

Comment: is `$result` really numeric in return? usually you get an array, and access that `\`d\`` index then compare it

Comment: do a `var_dump($Quantity_Ordered ,$number)` and paste the result here

Comment: @madalinivascu it prints 0, what the purpose of Var_dump? can you explain to me ?

Comment: @Ghost Thank you Gost, can you explain that in detail using my code because I tried your solution and it didn't work

Comment: @Fahad it should print 2 values,what is your second value?

Comment: assuming the query works fine including the fetching, usually you'll get an array, not an really an exact number, so by that statement, `$result` is not a number, but an array, you'll need to access it the value inside it first, most likely like this `return $result[0]['d']`, so that this condition `($Quantity_Ordered > $number)` satifies,

Comment: @madalinivascu it prints int (1) int(0)

Comment: @Fahad so you will get the error `This Number is not avaliable in our Stock !`

Comment: @Fahad what's the problem exactly?

Comment: @madalinivascu the problem is that in the database I have two values for the particular blood type, so it supposed to print two in the second value instead of 0, so it is supposed to go to the next condition instead of this one

Comment: @madalinivascu any help friend?

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be `$result = $statement->fetchAll();`(a function or method), not `$result = $statement->fetchall` (a property).

Second, please read the [manul](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), `fetchall()` return an array. therefore you can't cast it to int directly. run `print_r( $auth_user->Blood_Bankavaliable($Blood_BankID,$Type_Ordered) );` to see yourself.

Comment: can you explain to me how can I return int value directly from a function?

Comment: If you don't know how to access an array, then you really need to take a PHP course or read the [manual on array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Basically, an array consists of key->value pairs, you get to access the value of an element of any array using $array[key], e.g. $array[0] return the value of first element of the array.